# Why does screen of my phone stay on when listening to Spotify in my car?

Tags: samsung, screen, bluetooth-audio

Lately I have noticed that when I listen to Spotify while my phone is connected via Bluetooth to the car's speakers, the phone's screen is kept turned on indefinitely. Some specifics:

- The phone is Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra
- The car is Skoda with Columbus infotainment system
- Phone is charging via USB-C cable
- Car supports wireless charging when phone is in the locker, but I keep it on the locker's lid and it looks like it never charges wirelessly
- I'm unsure if the problem is only with Spotify or will it happen with other apps as well (need to check)

Where should I search for the settings to turn this "feature" off? Screen is configured to switch off in 2 minutes. I found no settings in Spotify nor in my car's setup to control the phone's screen.

Comment: Some phones tend to override the power saving settings while charging. Not really a problem because you can simply press the power button to turn the screen off. It has nothing to do with whatever device it is connected to and makes no sense whatsoever to try to find any related setting in the car.